Replace existing COM server while still sending messages to it
So I had the need to replace an existing Microsoft COM server with my own implementation. I did this with an in-process COM Server written in .NET 8.
In order to do this, I also took the same ProgID and GUID that the original COM Service were using and this works really really well.
Now I find myself having a new requirement, which is to basically forward all method invocations to the default implementation as well.
I don't really care if this is done through some existing COM mechanism that allows multiple stubs with the same GUID/ProgID to coexist, or through my COM server forwarding the messages to the other COM server itself or through any other method really.
Because both COM servers share the same GUID/ProgID I can't have them both be registered, which means that I also can't (from my COM server) create an instance of the other COM server using just the GUID/ProgID.
What I've tried so far was trying to create an instance of the original COM server through the path to the executable (it's an out-of-process COM server, unlike mine) and for that I used this code:
public class ComServerInterceptor
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CoGetObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName, ref BIND_OPTS3 pBindOptions, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv);

    private static Guid IID_IUnknown = new("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

    public static T CreateInstanceByPath<T>(string monikerName)
    {
        Log.Information("Starting CreateInstanceByPath");

        var pUnknown = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            //Process.Start(pathToExe);

            var bindOptions = new BIND_OPTS3
            {
                cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BIND_OPTS3)),
                dwClassContext = 0x4 // CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
            };

            var hr = CoGetObject(monikerName, ref bindOptions, ref IID_IUnknown, out pUnknown);

            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Exception");
        }

        return (T) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pUnknown);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct BIND_OPTS3
    {
        public int cbStruct;
        public int grfFlags;
        public int grfMode;
        public int dwTickCountDeadline;
        public int dwTrackFlags;
        public int dwClassContext;
        public int locale;
        public IntPtr pServerInfo;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    }
}

And called it as such: CreateInstanceByPath<MyComType>("file://C:/path/to/my/COMServer.exe"); but this throws 0x800401EA - MK_E_CANTOPENFILE
I don't know if I'm going in the completely wrong direction with how I'm attempting to get this done, or if I'm just one parameter away from getting this working, but could use some help.

This would have good chances to work with a .dll COM server, but you can't use an .exe COM server w/o all COM ceremony (registry, etc). If you have access to exe source, you'd better recompile it. If you don't have access to it, you could patch the binary (replace the found guids inplace, it's a hack but has lots of chance to work fine since such guids are pretty unique). PS: Not sure it's the culprit, but you shouldn' use unix-like '/' paths

@SimonMourier what about changing the ProgID/ID of my own COM server to something unique? Could I somehow then configure the COM proxy to call both registered stubs? Or any other crazy way of getting both COM servers getting running at the same time?

Not sure I understand what you say. If your client uses a progid and only a progid, you can use a new CLSID, change the CLSID where that progid points in the registry, and keep your exising code with it's existing CLSID

Was just a stupid idea but I realise that wouldn't work anyway.
